# Multi-threaded registration

Tags: .net, ninject, unity-container, structuremap, autofac

Is there any .net IOC container that has thread-safe type registrations?

I have many dozens of bindings that are fixed for the life of the application - but there are a few registrations that need to be adjusted on a "per-thread" or "per-request" basis.  When the threads of this app are recycled to/from the thread pool, the small handful of dynamic IOC registrations would be cleared or overwritten as new requests are dispatched.

To clarify, below is Unity-based sample code that combines a WCF service with the idea of a container "module" or "registry."

```
public class AccountServiceRegistry : UnityContainerExtension, IBindingOverride
{
    //From UnityContainerExtension
    protected override void Initialize() 
    {
        Container.RegisterType<IAccountService, AccountService>();
    }

    //From IBindingOverride
    public void ReInitialize(IUnityContainer child, string action, object[] parms){

        child.RegisterType<AccountService>(new InjectionProperty("log"), new InjectionProperty("dao"));

        child.AddNewExtension<DataAccessRegistry>();

        string connectionString = action == "GetMoreData" ? "Alpha" : "Bravo";

        child.Configure<IDataAccessConfig>().WithConnection(connectionString);
    }
}
```

In this sample, the `AcccountServiceRegisty` method `Initialize()` would be called once for the life of the application, but the `ReInitialize()` would be called with each WCF service request.  The `ReInitialize()` is given the name of the WCF operation that will execute, along with the parameters that will be supplied.  After `ReInitialize()` completes, one last Unity `BuildUp()` call is made on the service instance, and then the service operation executes.

As the example further illustrates, the info about the service call is used to determine what DB connection string the DataAccess instance will be instantiated with.

To create this behavior, I originally planned on creating a Unity child container for each request that needed unique bindings.  This is why the `ReInitialize()` call has a childContainer parameter passed in.  But then I discovered that `CreateChildContainer` itself does not appear to be thread safe.  Indeed I've found it difficult to find the thread-safety claims for any of the .net IOC containers (except for [Autofac, which makes it rather clear](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Concurrency)).

I suspect that a container allowing thread-safe registrations would make use of a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287189%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [immutable collections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/09/25/immutable-collections-ready-for-prime-time.aspx).  We'll see.

On the other hand, if I absolutely had to avoid this dynamic, multi-threaded registration process - I suppose I would make type-to-delegate registrations instead of type-to-type registrations.  This way the delegate could make a dynamic decision of what to create instead of the binding itself being dynamic.  In that case the prior example code would move all registrations from the `ReInitialize()` method into the `Initialize()` method, and the `IDataAccessConfig` implementation would change to look like this:

```
public class DataAccessRegistry: UnityContainerExtension, IDataAccessConfig
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    string connection;

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Container.RegisterType<IDataAccess>(new InjectionFactory(c => new DataAccess(connection)));
    }

    public IDataAccessConfig WithConnection(string connection)
    {
        this.connection = connection;
        return this;
    }
}
```

The key part for the above sample, is the `[ThreadStatic]` which ensures multiple threads can call `WithConnection()` safely.

But this doesn't change my question - is there a .net container that has thread-safe registrations?

Comment: Simple Injector makes [the same claim](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20the%20Simple%20Injector) about thead-safety as Autofac does. But if you need to register the container over multiple threads, you're doing something wrong. If you need per-request lifestyle, most frameworks have specific facilities for this.

Comment: Consider having a different lifetime per request or per unit of work (e.g., the way ASP.NET integration works in Autofac) rather than working on a per-thread basis if you can. It might make your life easier and would alleviate many of your multithreading concerns.

Comment: @Steven: Your comment prompted me to edit my question for clarity.  When you say "registering over multiple threads is wrong," what is the alternative?  Would you suggest the type-to-delegate bindings idea I added to my original question?

Comment: @BrentArias: Can you update your question with an example of the actual use case. That would allow me to give you feedback on that and show you how to go around this.

Comment: @Steven: Example code added.  It works exactly as desired - except I know it isn't thread safe and will explode in a real environment. :}

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

**Autofac has the feature**

All container operations are safe for use between *multiple threads*.

Resolution context objects are single-threaded and should not be used except during the course of a dependency resolution operation.

The container hierarchy mechanism further reduces locking, by maintaining local copies of the component registrations for any factory/container components. Once the initial registration copy has been made, a thread using an ‘inner’ container can create or access such components without blocking any other thread.

You can use **Autofac** to register services that are specific to a thread.

Thread-Safe Types
The following types are safe for concurrent access by multiple threads:

**Container**

**ComponentRegistry**

**Disposer** (default implementation of **IDisposer**)

**LifetimeScope** (default implementation of **ILifetimeScope**)

These types cover practically all of the runtime/resolution scenarios.

**ContainerBuilder** is designed for single-threaded access at configuration time